# SAMSUNG HD204UI EcoGreen HDD is being shown as almost broken

Tags: hard-drive

Windows prompted this error, recently:

[image]

I installed CrystalDiskInfo and checked out, what's happening. The **Spin-Up Time** is shown as critical. Is something wrong? Or is this just caused by the HDD being a EcoGreen HD?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskInfo 5.3.1 (C) 2008-2013 hiyohiyo
                                Crystal Dew World : http://crystalmark.info/
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    OS : Windows 8 Enterprise Edition [6.2 Build 9200] (x64)
  Date : 2013/02/21 16:38:41

-- Controller Map ----------------------------------------------------------
 + Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 Port SATA AHCI Controller - 1C02 [ATA]
   - M4-CT128M4SSD2
   - ATAPI iHAS624   B
   - SAMSUNG HD204UI
 - Microsoft-Controller für Speicherplätze [SCSI]

-- Disk List ---------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) M4-CT128M4SSD2 : 128,0 GB [0/0/0, pd1] - mi
 (2) SAMSUNG HM500JI : 500,1 GB [1/0/0, sa1]
 (3) SAMSUNG HD204UI : 2000,3 GB [2/0/0, pd1]

######################
   ... other devices
######################

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (3) SAMSUNG HD204UI
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : SAMSUNG HD204UI
        Firmware : 1AQ10001
   Serial Number : S2H7J9KB607575
       Disk Size : 2000,3 GB (8,4/137,4/2000,3)
     Buffer Size : 32767 KB
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 3907029168
   Rotation Rate : 5400 RPM
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ATA8-ACS
   Minor Version : ATA8-ACS version 6
   Transfer Mode : SATA/300
  Power On Hours : 1792 hours
  Power On Count : 792 count
     Temparature : 28 C (82 F)
   Health Status : Bad
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, AAM, 48bit LBA, NCQ
       APM Level : 0000h [OFF]
       AAM Level : FE00h [OFF]

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 100 100 _51 0000000004A8 Read Error Rate
02 252 252 __0 000000000000 Throughput Performance
03 __7 __1 _25 000000006E58 Spin-Up Time
04 _98 _98 __0 00000000088B Start/Stop Count
05 252 252 _10 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 252 252 _51 000000000000 Seek Error Rate
08 252 252 _15 000000000000 Seek Time Performance
09 100 100 __0 000000000700 Power-On Hours
0A 252 252 _51 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0B 252 252 __0 000000000000 Recalibration Retries
0C 100 100 __0 000000000318 Power Cycle Count
B5 100 100 __0 00000086A861 Unknown
BF 252 252 __0 000000000000 G-Sense Error Rate
C0 252 252 __0 000000000000 Power-off Retract Count
C2 _64 _64 __0 0022000B001C Temperature
C3 100 100 __0 000000000000 Hardware ECC recovered
C4 252 252 __0 000000000000 Reallocation Event Count
C5 252 252 __0 000000000000 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 252 252 __0 000000000000 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
C8 100 100 __0 000000000000 Write Error Rate
DF 252 252 __0 000000000000 Load/Unload Retry Count
E1 100 100 __0 00000000088C Load/Unload Cycle Count

-- IDENTIFY_DEVICE ---------------------------------------------------------
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
000: 0040 3FFF C837 0010 0000 0000 003F 0000 0000 0000
010: 5332 4837 4A39 4B42 3630 3735 3735 2020 2020 2020
020: 0000 FFFF 0004 3141 5131 3030 3031 5341 4D53 554E
030: 4720 4844 3230 3455 4920 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020
040: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 8010 4000 2F00
050: 4000 0200 0200 0007 3FFF 0010 003F FC10 00FB 0000
060: FFFF 0FFF 0000 0407 0003 0078 0078 0078 0078 0000
070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 001F 1706 0000 004C 0040
080: 01FF 0028 746B 7F69 4123 7469 BC41 4123 007F 00A3
090: 00A3 0000 FFFE 0000 FE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
100: 88B0 E8E0 0000 0000 0000 0000 4000 0000 5002 4E92
110: 0572 A693 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 401C
120: 401C 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0029 0000
130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
140: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0002 0000
170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 003F 0000 0000 0000
210: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1518 0000 0000
220: 0000 0000 101F 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
230: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0400 0000 0000 0000 0000
240: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
250: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 12A5

-- SMART_READ_DATA ---------------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 10 00 01 2F 00 64 64 A8 04 00 00 00 00 00 02 26
010: 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 23 00 07 01 58
020: 6E 00 00 00 00 00 04 32 00 62 62 8B 08 00 00 00
030: 00 00 05 33 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 2E
040: 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 24 00 FC FC 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 32 00 64 64 00 07 00 00 00
060: 00 00 0A 32 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0B 32
070: 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 32 00 64 64 18
080: 03 00 00 00 00 00 B5 22 00 64 64 61 A8 86 00 00
090: 00 00 BF 22 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 22
0A0: 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C2 02 00 40 40 1C
0B0: 00 0B 00 22 00 00 C3 3A 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C4 32 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C5 32
0D0: 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 30 00 FC FC 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 36 00 C8 C8 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 C8 2A 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DF 32
100: 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E1 32 00 64 64 8C
110: 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 EC 4F 00 5B
170: 03 00 01 00 02 FF 00 55 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E8

-- SMART_READ_THRESHOLD ----------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 10 00 01 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 19 00 00 00 00
020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
030: 00 00 05 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 33
040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 0F 00 00 00 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
060: 00 00 0A 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0B 00
070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00
080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 B5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 BF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00
0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C2 00 00 00 00 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C5 00
0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 00 00 00 00 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 C8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DF 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E1 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 86
```

### EDIT

I run this HDD for two years now and never had any kind of error prompts regarding a HDD.

Comment: Do "Seek Error Rate" and "Spin Retry Count" stay at 51, or are those numbers changing? ( For spin retry count it is bad if it is **decreasing**. It is the count of retry of spin start attempts. This attribute stores a total count of the spin start attempts to reach the fully operational speed (under the condition that the first attempt was unsuccessful. A decrease of this attribute value is a sign of problems in the hard disk mechanical subsystem. )

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a hardware expert. The first column describes the *Current*, the second the *Worst* and the third the *Threshold* value. So I suppose as soon as the *Current* value of 252 drops below 51 (Spin Retry Count), the value is evaluated as a critical one. Same for the Seek Error Rate. Doesn't actually matter, though. The values of all three columns are the same after a refresh, still. But I run the tool just for about 15 minutes.

Comment: overall, those smart stats don't look too bad, but the spin-up time is truly dreadful. that its a Green 5400RPM drive will contribute to that, but the manufacturer sets teh smart thresholds so it isn;t behaving the way that the manufacturer expected. Also apps that read and interpret SMART data do not always handle all drives with the same accuracy. Try looking at it with Speedfan and see if it too flags the spin-up time with similar data.

Comment: Speedfan shows me this: `Spin Up Time: 7 (Value), 1 (Worst), 25 (Warn)`. The warranty is three years. Should I better back up the data and retrieve a new HDD? Is this data enough to make use of warranty?

Comment: @ebeeb - First verify a replacement is covered in this situation.  Seagate will want the drive to fail one of the tests with their utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First back up alI data. If the drive is still under warranty, contact Samsung support for next steps.  They should have a diagnostic tool you will need to run to get an error code.

Also note that there are reports of firmware issues with the HD204UI.  This may not be related in any way but worth checking.

Note that Samsung is now part of Seagate so you need to check  [Seagate Support](http://www.seagate.com/support/?cmpid=lp_press_support)

Comment: Samsung's hard disk division is, not all of Samsung obviously.

Comment: Firmware: https://www.seagate.com/de/de/support/kb/samsung-hd204uijpexe-firmware-patchupdate-223571en/